# Only one tooltip at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip2

I have a table in my website and when i hover over a link i create a tooltip, the issue is that when i move my mouse over the links quickly multiple tooltips will be displayed as seen in the screenshot below,

[image: Multiple Tooltips]

I need to have only one tooltip on screen at a time and remove it if the user is no longer hovering. I create the tooltips in side the success function of an ajax call so i will only display the tooltip if the controller returns a status of true. The code for this can also be found below. Any suggestions on how i can ensure only one tooltip is displayed at a time. Thank you for any help you can give.

```
  function tooltip(){
           $('#tblOrder').on('mouseenter', '#alarmsTooltip', function(event) {

                var id = $(this).attr('value');

                var statusResponse;

                var selector = $(this);

                $.ajax({
                        url: '<%=Url.Action("Alarms") %>',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {id: id},
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (Response) {
                        if(Response.status == true)
                        {

                            var alarmTrans = '<%=GetTranslation(TranslationType.Label, "Alarms.tooltip", "Alarms") %>';
                            var warningTrans = '<%=GetTranslation(TranslationType.Label, "Warnings.tooltip", "Warnings") %>';
                            var html = "<table border='1' style= 'border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;'> <tr><th>" + alarmTrans + "<img src='" + '<%=Url.Content("~/App_Themes/Shared/Icons/bullet_red.png")%>' + "' style='float: right' >" + "</th><th> " + warningTrans + "<img src='" + '<%=Url.Content("~/App_Themes/Shared/Icons/bullet_orange.png")%>' + "' style='float: right'>" + "</th></tr>"; 

                            $(selector).qtip({        

                                content: {
                                text: html + Response.Response,
                                title: {
                                    text: '<%=GetTranslation(TranslationType.Label, "Alarms and Warnings.tooltip", "Alarms and Warnings") %>'
                                }

                                },
                                position: {
                                    target: 'mouse',
                                    adjust: {x:5,y:5}
                                },

                                show: {
                                    ready: true,
                                    effect: function () {
                                        $(this).slideDown();
                                }
                                },
                                style: {
                                    //classes: 'qtip-dark'
                                    classes: 'qtip-green'
                                },
                                hide: {

                                    effect: function () {
                                        $(this).slideUp();
                                    }
                                },
                                api: { 
                                        beforeShow: function() {
                                            $('.qtip:visible').not(this.elements.tooltip).qtip('hide').qtip('disable');
                                        },
                                        beforeHide: function() {
                                            $('.qtip:visible').not(this.elements.tooltip).qtip('enable');
                                        }
                                     }

                            }, event);
                        }

                        }
                });


 });
 };
```

Again thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Store the `AJAX` call in a `global` variable

```
requestAjax = $.ajax({ ... });
```

On the top of the function `tooltip()` just do

```
if(requestAjax) requestAjax.abort();
```

and then hide all the tooltips and and then proceed with the rest of the code.

and Add

```
$("#tblOrder").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).qtip("hide");;
});
```

Comment: Then the tooltips would still be visible though even when the user stops hovering over the field. It would not stop before the user hovers over a different field.

Answer (score 0):

Right now your function is called on the event `mouseenter`.

Create another event `mouseleave` with a function that aborts the `ajax` call with `storedAjax.abort()`. However for this to work you need to store the ajax call in a global variable first.